# C++ If/else if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am making a program (too much freetime) about cramer's rule and matrices. And somewhere, I have this problem where you will need to input "Yes" or "No". And If I typed other words (lol for example) it would not go to else if statement or ask the question again. How do I limit the answers to only Yes / No?

```
cout << "There! you have now your first equation! is it " << a << "x+"   << b << "y=" << e << "? Is it? Yes/No"<<endl;
cin >> z;
if ( z== "No" )
    {
        while ( z== "No" )
            {
                cout << "what is the value of x?"<<endl;
                cin >> a;
                cout << "\n"<<endl;
                cout << "what is the value of y?"<<endl;
                cin >> b;
                cout << "\n"<<endl;
                cout << "what is the value of answer?"<<endl;
                cin >> e;
                cout << "\n"<<endl;
                cout << "There! you have corrected your first equation! is it " << a << "x+" << b << "y=" << e << "? Is it? Yes/No"<<endl;
                cin >> z;
            }
    }
else if ( z== "Yes" )
    {
        cout << "We will now proceed!"<<endl;
    }
```

I am just a beginner in c++
using codeblocks

Comment: You can not control input values while accepting the input. You have to first accept input and then you can check condition whether the input accepted is correct or not. You can generate a warning for wrong inputs.

Comment: What is the type of `z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on the do while loop! It's a post test loop so you can verify if z was either yes or no. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

The basic idea is:
Do user input while user input is NOT equal to yes or no.

Basic example:

```
int x;
do {
    cout << "Please enter 1 or 0" << endl;
    cin >> x;
} while (x != 0 && x != 1);
```